# Using an IF formula with a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, if

I'm looking for some assistance with a formula to have Columns C & D populate with the conditional formatting of a pivot table in columns A & B.  I have the conditional formatting set to highlight cells with a value greater than 499 and less than -499.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nULzC.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Populate how? Do you mean copy the conditional formatting to those columns?

Comment: I am just needing the conditional formatted highlighted cells  to be listed in C & D.  I have a spreadsheet with about 1600 inventory adjustments listed and I just want to see the adjustments that were over 499 and less than -499.  I have the pivot table showing all of the adjustments but just want to see the specific  cells.

Answer (score 0):

## IF vs FILTER

I would typically use the [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) function, not [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2), because it would remove the data that I'm not interested in.  Both functions support multiple conditions.

## FILTER Version in `A1`

```
=FILTER(C:D,(ABS(C:C)>499)+(ABS(D:D)>499))
```

1. Formula [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)s the range `C:D` where the absolute value of either `C:C` or `D:D` is greater than `499`.
2. The [ABS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/abs-function-3420200f-5628-4e8c-99da-c99d7c87713c) (absolute) function is used to reduce the number of conditions required from four to two, because the same condition now works for both positive and negative numbers.  `ABS(-x) = ABS(x)`.
   Without [ABS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/abs-function-3420200f-5628-4e8c-99da-c99d7c87713c), the formula would instead be:

   ```
   =FILTER(C:D,(C:C>499)+(C:C<-499)+(D:D>499)+(D:D<-499))
   ```

## IF Version in `A1`

```
=IF((ABS(C:C)>499)+(ABS(D:D)>499),C:D,"")
```

1. Unlike the [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) version, the [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) version will return an array that is the same height as the ranges and the values will be in the same row position as in `C:D`.
2. The formula needs to be in a row that leaves enough rows below it for the range.  For example, if testing entire columns, the formula must be in row 1 or it will return a `#SPILL!` error as the result would need all the rows + 1.
3. You could modify the formula using [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) and [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) so it removes the empty rows below the last populated row, and the populated rows would still match up with your source data:

   ```
   =LET(
      arr,IF((ABS(C:C)>499)+(ABS(D:D)>499),C:D,""),
      INDEX(
        arr,
        SEQUENCE(SUMPRODUCT((MAX((INDEX(arr,,1)<>"")*ROW(C:C))))),
        {1,2}))
   ```